# Preemptive authentication with NTLM httpcomponents-client 4.x

Tags: authentication, ntlm, preemptive

Is it possible to use the approach outline [Preemptive Basic authentication with Apache HttpClient 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014700/preemptive-basic-authentication-with-apache-httpclient-4) with NTLM authentication?

Our app makes multiple single request from Java to windows server application. The requests aren't usually in a logical group. I was hoping to cut down on the handshaking and just preemptively pass the creds.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

NTLM auth scheme cannot be used preemptively. It is a complex, **state-full** authentication protocol that involves multiple (two in NTLMv1 and NTLMv2) challenge / response exchanges. Once authenticated an NTLM secured connection is associated with a particular user identity and all subsequent requests are executed within that context.