# connect over ssl without certificate

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to connect to my server over SSL port 443 without a certificate.

I'm getting an error thrown:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate

Reading other questions to solve the problem, the following code should work, but I'm still getting the error message.  What could I be doing wrong?

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

// Set verifier     
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(this.requestedURL);
httpget.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, httpget));

try
{
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
}
catch(java.lang.Throwable t) {}
```

Comment: See this answer here on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android#1000205

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are trying to connect to the Server URL from Java code. If so are you using a Self Signed Certificate? Or Do you have certificate generated from Third Party like versign, godaddy? I don't see anything related in your code about the root certificate, do you have any root certificate in keystore?

Comment: St3fan: That example does not go as far as the .execute.  So, I tried it anyway, and it still fails.  I copied it, pasted it, and added the execute right after the code.  Still fails.

Comment: Once look at this post. It is very good answer for HTTPS over 443 [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105681/https-connection-with-basic-auth-result-into-unauthorized/7157404#7157404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all other solutions, android 2.2 + needs special code.  This worked

[Custom SSL handling stopped working on Android 2.2 FroYo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899079/custom-ssl-handling-stopped-working-on-android-2-2-froyo)

Answer (score 0):

Your client truststore doesn't trust the server certificate. It is probably a self-signed certificate, so you need to import it into your clients truststore. Or get it signed by a CA. Ignoring the server certificate isn't secure, you may as well not use HTTPS at all.