# Apache HttpClient (4.1 and newer): how to do basic authentication?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

How do I add basic authentication for the default client of the httpClient library? I have seen examples where they use `client.getCredentialProvider()`, however I think all of this methods are for library version 4.0.1 or 3.x. Is there a new example of how to do this?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html

Comment: This is the best example I've found anywhere... way better than the apache documentation : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4328694/967980

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We do basic authentication with `HttpClient`, but we do not use `CredentialProvider`. Here's the code:

```
HttpClient client = factory.getHttpClient(); //or any method to get a client instance
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
```

**UPDATE:**
A stated in the comments, the `HttpClient.getState()` methos is available in [version 3.x of the API](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/). However, [newer versions of the API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/) doesn't support that method.

Comment: That's great, but HttpClient.getState() doesn't exist in the 4.x code. This is only applicable for 3.1 and earlier.

Comment: Am I the only one confused as to why this is the accepted answer?

Answer (score 86):

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = 
    HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
```

Comment: This is the best answer for v4.3. Just be careful that it will send the credentials preemptively to *all* URLs.

Comment: To solve for artbristol's concern, change the AuthScope.

Comment: @artbristol Only if you have preemptive auth configured, right? ["HttpClient does not support preemptive authentication out of the box"](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)

Comment: @bmaupin yes I think you're right. This will send the credentials to any server that demands them, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 20):

Didn't you download the example from the website?And examples are here: httpcomponents-client-4.1.3\examples\org\apache\http\examples\client

As for https,Just see ClientAuthentication.java:

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 *
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 */

package org.apache.http.examples.client;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * A simple example that uses HttpClient to execute an HTTP request against
 * a target site that requires user authentication.
 */
public class ClientAuthentication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("localhost", 443),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://localhost/protected");

            System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

So in short :

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("localhost", 443),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
```

Comment: DefaultHttpClient is deprecated in 4.x. You can use an example https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java from https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html .

Comment: DefaultHttpClient has been deprecated only in 4.3. It is not deprecated in 4.1

Answer (score 10):

Another modern option for 4.3 is to use the Fluent extension:

```
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance()
        .auth(new HttpHost("somehost"), "username", "password")
        .auth(new HttpHost("securehost", 443, "https"), "username", "password") // https example
        .auth(new HttpHost("myproxy", 8080), "username", "password")
        .authPreemptive(new HttpHost("myproxy", 8080));

String content = executor.execute(Request.Get("http://somehost/"))
        .returnContent().asString();
```

Comment: Having struggle a bit to make this work on an https connection, one need no to forget to add port and scheme on HttpHost (new HttpHost("somehost", 443, "https"), as default port and scheme are 80, http.

Comment: What is the full import path for `Executer`? I'm getting an error for `.newInstance()`. Compiler says that doesn't exist. Which version of JDK are you using?

Comment: `org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor` http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor.html

Answer (score 4):

DefaultHttpClient has getCredentialsProvider() but HttpClient doesn't.
You need to declare
DefaultHttpClient client = ...
instead of
HttpClient client = ...

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` is now deprecated in 4.3, despite only being introduced in 4.0!

Answer (score 0):

I had this requirement of invoking a URL with Basic Authentication which also required proxy settings.
This is what worked for me.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
    import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
    import org.w3c.dom.*;

    import javax.xml.parsers.*;


    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

    public class TestResponse {

    public final static String TESTURL="https://myURL";
    private static final String PROXY_HOST = "www2.proxyXYS";
    private static final int PROXY_PORT = 8080;


    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(TESTURL);
    HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
    config.setProxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

      String username = "User";
      String password = "Pa55w0rd";


    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

    client.getState().setProxyCredentials(authScope, credentials);
    client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    try {
        client.executeMethod(method);

        String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();

        if (method.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
             response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection();
    }
}





}
```