# HttpClient 4.2, Basic Authentication, and AuthScope

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I have an application connecting to sites that require basic authentication. The sites are provided at run time and not known at compile time.

I am using HttpClient 4.2.

I am not sure if the code below is how I am supposed to specify basic authentication, but the documentation would suggest it is. However, I don't know what to pass in the constructor of `AuthScope`. I had thought that a null parameter meant that the credentials supplied should be used for all URLs, but it throws a `NullPointerException`, so clearly I am wrong.

```
m_client = new DefaultHttpClient();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(m_userName, m_password);
((DefaultHttpClient)m_client).getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope((HttpHost)null), credentials);
```

Comment: client.getCredentialsProvider(). setCredentials(
 new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort),
 new UsernamePasswordCredentials( proxyUser, proxyPassword));
This is correct way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AuthScope.ANY is what you're after: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/auth/AuthScope.html

Try this:

```
    final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
    client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
    final GetMethod method = new GetMethod(uri);
    client.executeMethod(method);
```

Comment: Thank you Kieran. I don't have a `getState` method on the client, but I guess we are just using different versions. I tried `AuthScope.ANY` as you suggested and it worked - thank you. Can I just ask you one other question - is the `setAuthenticationPreemptive(true)` necessary/recommended?

Comment: Took me a while to see this comment. The `setAuthenticationPreemptive(true)` means the crendentials will be sent in the initial request without requiring an attempted request first without credentials and then getting a 401 and then providing them once challenged.

Comment: This methods are not available in HttpClient4.1

Answer (score 3):

From at least version 4.2.3 (I guess after version 3.X), the accepted answer is no longer valid. Instead, do something like:

```
private HttpClient createClient() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");

    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password");
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    return httpclient;
}
```

The JavaDoc for `AuthScope.ANY` says *In the future versions of HttpClient the use of this parameter will be discontinued*, so use it at your own risk. A better option would be to use one of the constructors defined in `AuthScope`.

For a discussion on how to make requests preemptive, see:

[Preemptive Basic authentication with Apache HttpClient 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014700/preemptive-basic-authentication-with-apache-httpclient-4)