# Solr Change CommonsHttpSolrServer To HttpSolrServer

Tags: solr, solrj

For Basic Authentication in solr 3.5 I am using the following code,

```
String url = "http://192.168.192.11:8080/solr/FormResponses";
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer( url );
String username = "user";
String password = "user123";
Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
server.getHttpClient().getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);
server.getHttpClient().getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
```

In solr 4.0 `CommonsHttpSolrServer` is not available, so I want to replace it with
`HttpSolrServer`. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: What is the problem? instead of CommonsHttpSolrServer just use HttpSolrServer.

Comment: @parvin CommonsHttpSolrServer is not in solrj4.jar so I need a new method using HttpSolrServer instead of CommonsHttpSolrServer.

Comment: @parvin In  HttpSolrServer  getHttpClient() method is not avilable

Comment: It is available. Check this out. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.html#getHttpClient()

Comment: @parvin In CommonsHttpSolrServer if I use 
server.getHttpClient().getState() it is giving some value
BUT 
IN HttpSolrServer if I use
server.getHttpClient().getState() it shows error.
Please run the above simple code and help me to fix

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: The type org.apache.http.client.HttpClient cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
---It is a compilation error

Comment: Add apache httpclient,httpcore and httpmime jars to your classpath.

Comment: Still Not solved:
Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "user123");
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client .getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);
  client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
  HttpSolrServer serverNEW = new HttpSolrServer( url,client );

The constructor HttpSolrServer(String, HttpClient) is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find the answer my self,

```
String url = "http://192.168.192.11:8080/solr/FormResponses";
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "user123"));
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(url, httpclient);
```

Answer (score 8):

Change the code as follows :

```
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;

String url = "http://192.168.192.11:8080/solr/FormResponses";
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer( url );
DefaultHttpClient client = (DefaultHttpClient) server.getHttpClient();

UsernamePasswordCredentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "user123");
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);
```

For `server.getHttpClient().getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true)` in HttpClient 4 you can use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014700/preemptive-basic-authentication-with-apache-httpclient-4).

Comment: It shows  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient 
---Can you provide your import statements

Comment: +1 for your effect. Thank you, Finally I find the Solution Myself

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the JAR [solr-solrj-4.0.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsolrsolrj400jar.htm) for HttpClientUtil .

Then use below code :

```
HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr/"+url);     
HttpClientUtil.setBasicAuth((DefaultHttpClient) solrServer.getHttpClient(),
                            "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
```

That worked for me.

Comment: this works for read operations but not for solr write.(since the connection is not preemptive)

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way that works for me:

```
String url = "192.168.192.11:8080/solr/FormResponses";
String username = "user";
String password = "user123";
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + url);
```