# POST using SOAPUI works. Manual Java client using Apache HttpComponents HttpClient doesn't. Throwing server error. SSL related?

Tags: java, apache, https, soapui, apache-commons-httpclient

**Please note that I've tested the following in SOAPUI and it appears to work as expected (i.e. returning a 200 status) using the same URL and Authorization credentials. The fact that it works OK in SOAPUI makes me think I should be doing something specific when building my request to handle the fact that it's https.**

Attempting to POST to a URL using DefaultHttpClient (v4.2.3) using the following method:

```
String requestUrl = "https://test.host.name:9093/ws/simple/serviceName";
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestUrl);

String username = "username@domainname";
String password = "pass-word-string";
String usernameAndPassword = username + ":" + password;
String encodedUserNameAndPassword = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(usernameAndPassword.getBytes());
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", encodedUserNameAndPassword);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();           
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(responseString);

EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

The problem I'm having is that the server is responding with a 400 status and Bad Request message:

```
[DEBUG] wire - << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] wire - << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] wire - << "Server: Jetty(6.1.26-boomi)[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] wire - << "[\r][\n]"
```

If I remove the authentication part then I get a "401 Not Authorized" which at least indicates that the server is expecting my request:

```
[DEBUG] wire - << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] wire - << "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="BoomiBasicRealm"[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] wire - << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] wire - << "Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] wire - << "Content-Length: 1396[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] wire - << "Server: Jetty(6.1.26-boomi)[\r][\n]"
```

The server admin has said that he can see the following coming through to the server logs:

```
SSL renegotiate denied: java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/192.168.20.86:9093 remote=/ip.ip.ip.ip:61356]”
```

The strange thing is that I've used the same code to post successfully to other URLs which are using https, albeit not using a different port in the address, and it works without an issue.

The server admin is looking at it from their end while I continue to investigate but the fact that it works in SOAPUI makes me think there is something I need to do differently.

I noticed that SOAPUI is using Apache-HttpClient v4.1.1 whereas I'm using 4.2.3 so I switched to 4.1.1 and it didn't make a difference. Therefore I'm guessing that SOAPUI is doing something different under the covers which I need to mimic.

Are there any SOAPUI devs out there who might be able to advise?

Comment: try to hit service URL with browser. Looks like problem in SSL certificate, not in Basic Authorization.

Comment: Hitting the URL in a browser doesn't throw any errors. The basic authorization part appears to be working ok. The problem is once I'm past the authorization part.

Comment: Who issued server Sertificate? If server used self-signed cert, you can fetch if (from browser, for example), store somewhere on hard drive and add it to JRE cacert. `cd $JRE_HOME/lib/security` `keytool -importcert -keystore cacerts -file /path/to/CA.pem -alias test`.

Comment: It's a DigiCert High Assurance CA-3 certificate so not self-signed.

Comment: i would suggest set property -Djavax.net.debug=all and run code again. Maybe it reveals something curious.

Comment: I've been through and followed the following article (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) with -Djavax.net.debug=all enabled. All appears to be ok and yet the server still returns a response code 400. And yet when I POST to the same URL in SOAPUI, it works OK.

Comment: Does the same code work for a http request? (without the s)

Comment: The server I'm calling isn't accepting any requests over just http so I can't test.

Comment: @lee_mcmullen Could you post request wire logs?

Comment: take a look at the SOAPUI HTTP log to see what it actually sending compared to what you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should enable [HttpClient's preemtive authorization](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#d5e1032) instead of adding `Authorization` header by hand.

See also [Preemptive Basic authentication with Apache HttpClient 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014700/preemptive-basic-authentication-with-apache-httpclient-4)

Answer (score 0):

The sun Base64 encoder will add newlines after a certain number of characters.  if your encoded username/password is too long, you will be sending a broken authorization header.  trying removing any whitespace from the encode authorization value.  (as a side note, you should always use an explicit encoding with `String.getBytes()`)

```
String encodedUserNameAndPassword = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
    .encode(usernameAndPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    .replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

That said, i'm pretty sure apache http client can handle this for you.  You should probably be following [this example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java).