# Exception connecting to Remote Solr Instance (407 error)

Tags: java, apache, search, solrj, solrcloud

I have written the code mentioned below.

```
HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://10.40.4.171/solr/prime-core");
List<UserSolr> userList=null;
        SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery();
        q.setQuery("*:*");
        q.setStart(0);
        q.setRows(10);
        //SolrDocumentList results = null;
        try {
            QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(q);
            userList=response.getBeans(UserSolr.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

But for the above I get the following error :-

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Server at http://10.40.4.171/solr/prime-core returned non ok status:407, message:Proxy Authorization Required
```

I am not able to resolve this problem. Same code is working fine with the url `http://localhost:8080/solr/prime-core` Please let me know how to modify to connect to the server without error.

Thanks.

Note:
prime-core is my Solr Core
I am using Solr 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP code `407` implies `Proxy Authentication Required`, you need to set authentication information while making connection to server via `HttpClient`:

```
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    AuthScope.ANY,
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(solrUrl, httpclient);//with credentials
```

you may like to check similar discussions:

> [Solr - instantiate HttpSolrServer with Httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802499/solr-instantiate-httpsolrserver-with-httpclient)
>
> [Solr 4 with basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427546/solr-4-with-basic-authentication)

Comment: The username and password implies the username and password of the proxy?? Right?