# Solrj IOException occured when talking to server

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I am using basic authentication. My solr version is 4.1. I can get query results but when I try to index documents I am getting the following error message:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://192.168.0.1:8983/solr/my_core
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:102)
    at warningletter.Process.run(Process.java:128)
    at warningletter.WarningLetter.parseListPage(WarningLetter.java:81)
    at warningletter.WarningLetter.init(WarningLetter.java:47)
    at warningletter.WarningLetter.main(WarningLetter.java:21)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:822)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:353)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:625)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    ... 11 more
```

This is my code piece:

```java
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://192.168.0.1:8983/solr/warning_letter/", httpclient);
SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
solrDoc.addField("id", "id1");
solrDoc.addField("letter", "letter");
server.add(solrDoc);
server.commit();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue; ping is working but adding a doc is throwing the above error

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the preemptive authentication so as to avoid the need to repeat the query after the "unauthorized" response is sent. 
Here is the example
[Preemptive Basic authentication with Apache HttpClient 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014700/preemptive-basic-authentication-with-apache-httpclient-4/11868040#11868040)