# Solr 6.6: IOException "when talking to server"

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, ioexception

I have configured Solr 6.6.x version with Single core and Single shard. The document index are few Million webpage. From client (Solrj), I am just requesting URL of each document. There are 40 threads to do this and in each request, I have configured 100 documents (urls) to get from solr. So overall, I can say that 40x100 = 4000 documents are requested simultaneously. Solr in running in standalone mode with 20 GB RAM.

In my case, Solr server and client are on same system. The idea was to know about how many requests Solr Server can handle at a time. During execution of about configuration client, I have observed following exception

```
2018-12-26 10:56:31 WARN  RunJobWorker:78 - Exception: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://127.0.0.1:8900/solr/collection1
2018-12-26 10:56:31 WARN  RunJobWorker:78 - Exception: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://127.0.0.1:8900/solr/collection1
2018-12-26 10:56:31 WARN  RunJobWorker:78 - Exception: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://127.0.0.1:8900/solr/collection1
2018-12-26 10:56:31 WARN  RunJobWorker:78 - Exception: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://127.0.0.1:8900/solr/collection1
2018-12-26 10:56:31 WARN  RunJobWorker:78 - Exception: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://127.0.0.1:8900/solr/collection1
```

Sometime it is observed ( in few threads) and sometimes, it is gone. But this is happening ? I think It is not memory problem as otherwise solr server should be down with OOM exception. I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627224/solrj-ioexception-occured-when-talking-to-server) but it was for Solr 4.1 version, a long time ago. 
What are the possible ways to debug this issue. Being on the same system, there should not be any bandwidth problem. The machine, I am using to test have 48 core and 94 GB RAM.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in the server log?

Comment: No I do not get any exception in server log.

Comment: So what is the complete Exception returned by your client? It should indicate if it even made contact to the HTTP server at all. The bundled jetty might be too busy to handle the requests with the default settings, and the request never makes its way to Solr.

Comment: Is it possible to changes jetty default setting so that it can handle large number of requests as in my case ?

Comment: Sure, but first you'll have to determine that it actually is the cause of the error - don't start by doing that, start by finding out what the actual error that causes the exception is. It should be in the complete stack trace.

Comment: During a little tweaking, I reduced number of threads to 20 from 40 and increase docs from 100 to 200 docs per request. Then this Exception is reduced. What does it mean ?

Comment: It sounds like my guess might have something to do with it - but the stack trace should tell you what the original cause of the error is. You can also try by having nginx or something similar in front of Solr to buffer requests. For Jetty you'd change the `Acceptors` parameter (iirc) to change the number of threads waiting to handle requests, but I'm not up to date on how this is configured in the bundled version for Solr at the moment.