# Make GET request via HTTP/Basic Auth to a website with an untrusted certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, get, basic-authentication

Basically, I need to access a "secure" (outdated certificate) server through an http GET request with basic authentication in the header and print (for now) the XML I get from it. I have the code running on C#, as such:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(BaseUri, apiUrl));
        request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        if (accept != null)
            request.Accept = accept;
        request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, crt, chain, ssl) => true;
        AddAuthHeaderBasicFromCredentials(request, ApiCredentials);
        try
        {
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            return response.GetResponseStream();
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

As far as my java code goes, this is what I have:

```
public class Main {
static {
    //for localhost testing only
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
    new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

        public boolean verify(String hostname,
                javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {    
                return true;
        }
    });
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String webPage = "https://blabla.com";
        String name = "user";
        String password = "pass";

        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        HttpURLConnection HttpurlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        HttpurlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        HttpurlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        InputStream is = HttpurlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }
        String result = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("*** END ***");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

It works fine on any website that doesn't require authentication but whenever I try to access the website I'm aiming for I get an error saying:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The static block at the start of the class was my attempt to bypass the problems I'm having with the certificate. I'm aware it isn't a recommended approach but this is merely for a test and I need it to run.

Thanks in advance, I'll gladly give any information you might need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062307/pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested). You haven't included any custom truststore that's why java falls back on the default one which does not accept self-signed certificates. Either add the certificate manually or define a truststore as explained in the link above (although the thread has no accepted solution)

Comment: If Apache's HttpClient is acceptable for you eventually [this link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679320/basic-authentication-using-http-commons-client/19679722#19679722) might be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) - I'm pretty sure if you look at the first answer at that question, you will get what you want.