# Writing java client for ssl authentication

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have create an openssl certificate by following these commands

```
D:\softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin>openssl genrsa -out serverprivatekey.pem 2048

D:\softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin>openssl req -new -x509 -key serverprivatekey.pem -out servercert.pem -days 1095

D:\softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin>openssl pkcs12 -export -out serverkeystore.pkcs12 -in servercert.pem -inkey serverprivatekey.pem

D:\softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin>keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore serverkeystore.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

I configured the `server.xml` file of the tomcat and enabled the HTTPS. It worked perfectly fine when i opened the site on web browser.

Now I am trying to write a java client for this using Java8 and Apache HttpClient 4.5. I wrote following code

```
  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://localhost:8443/first/rest/hello");
  CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
  System.out.println( response.getStatusLine());
```

And I am getting follwoing exception. Do i have to add the certificate in java keystore ? Or what ? I already did that but that keystore was executed from tomcat home directory. Not sure what to do.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1478)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at com.vogella.jersey.first.Test.usingApacheHttp(Test.java:34)
    at com.vogella.jersey.first.Test.main(Test.java:27)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1460)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: As you are using a custom truststore with a self-signed certificate, you need to create a SSLContext and load the custom truststore to it similar to [this example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679320/basic-authentication-using-http-commons-client/19679722#19679722)

Answer (score 0):

Your Java clients truststore doent trust the server certificate. You have to either:

1. Export it from the server keystore into the client truststore, or better
2. Get it signed by a CA.