# Why are requests sent twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I have a winforms client application that uses `HttpClient` to connect to a WebApi2 app. I'm currently testing locally so the server starts using IIS Express 10.

The server app allows anonymous and also windows authentication. Every controller has the `Authorize` attribute.

The `HttpClient` is set up as follows:

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler()
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
    CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
    Credentionals = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
    UseCookies = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    UseProxy = false,
};
client = new HttpClient(handler, true)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(myUrl)
};
```

And to make sure, I also do:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", Credentials.UserName, Credentials.Password))));
```

The application works fine, however the following is a snippet of the log being generated by IIS Express:

> 10:51:11 ::1 POST /myserver/Login - 55567 - ::1 - - 401 0 0 389
>
> 10:51:17 ::1 POST /myserver/Login - 55567 MicrosoftAccount\myemail@here.com ::1 - - 200 0 0 5760
>
> 10:51:51 ::1 POST /myserver/SearchFor itemType=38 55567 - ::1 - - 401 0 0 347
>
> 10:51:52 ::1 POST /myserver/SearchFor itemType=38 55567 MicrosoftAccount\myemail@here.com ::1 - - 200 0 0 815
>
> 10:51:55 ::1 GET /myserver/CustomerType/174 - 55567 - ::1 - - 401 0 0 400
>
> 10:51:55 ::1 GET /myserver/CustomerType/174 - 55567 MicrosoftAccount\myemail@here.com ::1 - - 200 0 0 574

For every request there's a `401` then a '200' code. I'm not explicitly setting the `WWW-Authenticate` header when sending the request.

How can I determine what kind of challenge the server is sending to the client?

**EDIT**

I've changed the initialization of `HttpClient` as follows:

```
var uri = new Uri(myUrl);

var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(new Uri(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), "NTLM", credentials);
        
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler()
{
    AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
    Credentials = credentialCache,
    PreAuthenticate = true,
};
client = new HttpClient(handler, true)
{
    BaseAddress = uri
};
```

On `GET` requests I always get a `401` followed by a `200` response. On other requests (`POST`, `PATCH`) there is only the `200` which I assume the client sent the authentication header correctly.

Why am I still getting a `401` on `GET` requests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpGet 401 status code followed by 200 status code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818587/httpget-401-status-code-followed-by-200-status-code)

Comment: @Thomas That question is for Android, which also has HttpClient but not related to .NET's HttpClient.

Comment: It's not language specific, it's HTTP specific. But ok, then use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6338985/4136325

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my Http client making 2 requests when I specify credentials?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338942/why-my-http-client-making-2-requests-when-i-specify-credentials)

Comment: @Thomas you should be more specific. All such authentication methods are called "challenge based" (Windows authentication/Kerberos/NTLM/Digest/Basic and so on), so 401/200 matches the "challenge" part.