# Android http file transfer

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I want to transfer file from my android application to http address.I written following code but doesnt work.The address of `hhtp=192.168.0.1:8181` with `username=admin` and `password=blank`.

Where should i set username and password for http file transfer

```
String url = "http://192.168.0.1:8181";
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File file = new File(dir,DATABASE_NAME);
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...
    Log.e("file transfer", "done");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // show error
    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Which kind of authentication does the server require? For Basic authentication for instance you would add an `Authorization` header.

Comment: Actually its dlink dir506 device address.When i enter the address 192.168.0.1:8181 in adrress bar of browser page it then ask for username and password .So i dont know type of Authorization

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments most likely Basic authentication is used. See [RFC 1945](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt), section 11.1 for the details. This means a header of the form

```
Authorization: Basic <base64-encoded-auth-info>
```

must be added to the request. The `base64-encoded-auth-info` is the string username:password:

```
admin:blank
```

encoded with base64.

All together:

```
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Ymxhbms=
```

Comment: Can you post any link of the example as i m new to it

Comment: I am not really familiar with the Apache HTTP client and btw. it is also deprecated in Android now; but this link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014700/preemptive-basic-authentication-with-apache-httpclient-4/4328694#4328694