# Proxy-Authorization header is not send within first request in Apache HttpComponents

Tags: java, scala, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using [Apache HttpComponents (4.5.2)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) and I'm trying to request HTTPS page via proxy server (SSH Tunneling).

The problem is that according to logs Client sends first request without `Proxy-Authorization` header, but after Proxy respond with 407 error (Proxy Authentication Required), it retires authentication with sending `Proxy-Authorization` header.

I think problem in my code, I need something like enabling primitive auth , but I couldn't find any information about how to do that.

Below is logs for confirming my words.

First request:

```
03:12:06,643 DEBUG headers:135 - http-outgoing-0 >> CONNECT t.myhost.com:443 HTTP/1.1
03:12:06,643 DEBUG headers:138 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: t.myhost.com
03:12:06,643 DEBUG headers:138 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_45)

03:12:06,793 DEBUG headers:124 - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
03:12:06,794 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="ProxyCompany"
03:12:06,794 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << Proxy-Connection: close
```

// then it retries request with included `Proxy-Authorization` header

```
03:12:06,795 DEBUG HttpAuthenticator:77 - Authentication required
03:12:06,795 DEBUG HttpAuthenticator:107 - 162.243.116.56:71223 requested authentication
03:12:06,795 DEBUG ProxyAuthenticationStrategy:174 - Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, Digest, Basic]
03:12:06,795 DEBUG ProxyAuthenticationStrategy:203 - Challenge for Negotiate authentication scheme not available
03:12:06,796 DEBUG ProxyAuthenticationStrategy:203 - Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available
03:12:06,796 DEBUG ProxyAuthenticationStrategy:203 - Challenge for NTLM authentication scheme not available
03:12:06,796 DEBUG ProxyAuthenticationStrategy:203 - Challenge for Digest authentication scheme not available
03:12:06,800 DEBUG HttpAuthenticator:157 - Selected authentication options: [BASIC [complete=true]]
03:12:06,800 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:81 - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
03:12:06,801 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:138 - Connecting to /162.243.116.56:71223
03:12:06,942 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:145 - Connection established 192.168.0.100:13391<->162.243.116.56:71223
03:12:06,942 DEBUG HttpAuthenticator:198 - Generating response to an authentication challenge using basic scheme
03:12:06,947 DEBUG headers:135 - http-outgoing-0 >> CONNECT t.myhost.com:443 HTTP/1.1
03:12:06,947 DEBUG headers:138 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: t.myhost.com
03:12:06,947 DEBUG headers:138 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_45)
03:12:06,947 DEBUG headers:138 - http-outgoing-0 >> Proxy-Authorization: Basic bHVtXXXXXXXXXXXXxOTE5NTUXXXXXXRmNmRkYmI1Mjk0MA==

03:12:07,304 DEBUG HttpAuthenticator:86 - Authentication succeeded
03:12:07,305 DEBUG ProxyAuthenticationStrategy:227 - Caching 'basic' auth scheme for http://162.243.116.56:71223
```

And this is my code (it's Scala, but pretty easy to read):

```
val credProvider = {
  val provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider()
  provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myUser", "myPass"))
  provider
}

val connManager = {
  val mngr  = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()
  mngr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  mngr.setMaxTotal(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  mngr
}

val client = HttpClients.custom()
  .setConnectionManager(connManager)
  .disableRedirectHandling()
  .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credProvider)
  .setProxy(new HttpHost(162.243.116.56, 71223 ))
  .build()

     val requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
       .setConnectTimeout(30000)
       .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000)
       .build()


     val request = new HttpGet(url)
     request.setConfig(requestConfig)
     val response = client.execute(request)
```

How I can solve this problem (cause client to always send `Proxy-Authorization` )?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014700/preemptive-basic-authentication-with-apache-httpclient-4?rq=1 links to (official but 'discouraged') http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java and then rings several variations on it and on just doing `.addHeader` manuallly.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same problem with java.net.HttpURLConnection. The "Proxy-Authorization" header is not sent in the initial request if the protocol is HTTPS. As a result, the server responds with a HTTP 407. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the same problem, but with version 4.5.2 there was a bug introduced with the SPN (HTTP/something@somerealm) and https : [HTTPCLIENT-1712](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1712) (the comments are especially interesting since they show a history of what happened).

A switch to version 4.5.1 should solve it (if this is the same problem of course)