# Authentication with apache solr

Tags: solr

[Github Link](https://github.com/bkatwal/kafka-solr-sink-connector)

Missing username and password properties from the solr connector configuration to authenticate with the solr.

Is that possible to authenticate with solr via connector config?

How to pass username n password within the connector config?

Comment: Have you tried including the `user:pass` combination in the URL as you'd do with a regular http url including username and password? (`http://username:password@host/..`)

Comment: Yes I have Tried it but still getting same issue.

Comment: According to the source it seems you can use `solr.username` and `solr.password` to provide authentication details. https://github.com/bkatwal/kafka-solr-sink-connector/blob/f0d022607f3d5419053bfb0c87a710fb37e00896/src/main/java/com/bkatwal/kafkaproject/SolrSinkConnectorConfig.java#L37

Comment: Yes I Have Checked it n it gives me error like Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://IP:PORT/solr: Expected mime type
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 require authentication</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 require authentication</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/FX_TRAN/update</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>require authentication</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like solr.username and solr.password aren't actually used in the connector.  The SolrClient is created with a default HttpSolrClient without any credentials in [this source file in Github](https://github.com/bkatwal/kafka-solr-sink-connector/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bkatwal/kafkaproject/utils/SolrClientFactory.java).   But [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh)'s point about embedding username and password in the URL is a good one and I'd have expected it to work.

There's a relevant thread here:

[Solr6.3.0 SolrJ API for Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225035/solr6-3-0-solrj-api-for-basic-authentication)

I haven't vetted the last answer in the thread, which doesn't really address the original topic in that post, but it is a concise example of creating a SolrClient with authentication.  The SolrClient needs to wrap an underlying HttpClient that provides the basic auth, and the Kafka Solr sink connector isn't doing that.